# nGinx throws internal server error when referring routes

Tags: nginx, centos, symfony, php-7

just installed LEMP stack on CentOS 7, which includes PHP 7..
I uploaded Symfony 3 project and my problem is that, when I try to access routes, it says just Internal Server error, for example: when I am redirected to `/login` by `fos_user_bundle` there is that internal server error.
I looked at error logs and they are looking like this:

`2017/02/08 11:51:35 [error] 488#0: *1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: <ip address>, server: mydomain.ge, request: "GET /foldername/web/app_dev.php/login HTTP/1.1", host: "mydomain.ge"`

```
server {
    listen   80;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  mydomain.ge <server ip address>;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

and my configuration file (example.conf) looks like this above.

Any ideas?

Comment: If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri specified in the last parameter is made. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

Answer (score 0):

If you want `/login` to be processed by `index.php` you need to add `index.php` to the try files.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```